# Apache Spark: Timeout Exception when processing large amount of data from S3

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-s3, pyspark

I am getting a timeout exception when I am reading data from S3 and processing it in Apache Spark. The error is as follows:

```
Lost task 5.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 5, prbatchs0004apse01.in.bsbportal.com): java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:152)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:122)
at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:442)
at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readV3Record(InputRecord.java:554)
at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:509)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:934)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:891)
at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:102)
at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.read(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:198)
at org.apache.http.impl.io.ContentLengthInputStream.read(ContentLengthInputStream.java:178)
at org.apache.http.impl.io.ContentLengthInputStream.read(ContentLengthInputStream.java:200)
at org.apache.http.impl.io.ContentLengthInputStream.close(ContentLengthInputStream.java:103)
at org.apache.http.conn.BasicManagedEntity.streamClosed(BasicManagedEntity.java:164)
at org.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream.checkClose(EofSensorInputStream.java:227)
at org.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream.close(EofSensorInputStream.java:174)
at org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils.consume(EntityUtils.java:88)
at org.jets3t.service.impl.rest.httpclient.HttpMethodReleaseInputStream.releaseConnection(HttpMethodReleaseInputStream.java:102)
at org.jets3t.service.impl.rest.httpclient.HttpMethodReleaseInputStream.close(HttpMethodReleaseInputStream.java:194)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.NativeS3FileSystem$NativeS3FsInputStream.seek(NativeS3FileSystem.java:152)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.BufferedFSInputStream.seek(BufferedFSInputStream.java:89)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataInputStream.seek(FSDataInputStream.java:63)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LineRecordReader.<init>(LineRecordReader.java:126)
```

Can anybody help me out with this?

Comment: Have you found a solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
##solve downloading data timeout problem
System.setProperty("sun.net.client.defaultReadTimeout", "30000")
```